# android googleMap - how to launch two camera update animations?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

i have two animations i want to perform on a google map in sequence.  So after animation 1 is finished then animation 2 can move on.

this can be done easily with a call back like this:

```
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), horizontalBounds, verticalBounds, 8), object : GoogleMap.CancelableCallback {
        override fun onCancel() {
            animationCompletionBlock()
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            //start the second animation
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16f), object : GoogleMap.CancelableCallback {
                override fun onFinish() {
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                }

            })
```

my question is about code quality i guess cleaniness. i want to know if there is a easier or better way to sequence the animation.  like is there a way to provide an array of camera updates to fire off in sequence by a google API.. it looks awful to have to call another animation inside of onFinish of hte first camera animation. The call backs look ugly, a bit of a smell.  is there way design pattern or build in way to make it look better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only way to do animation sequence in Google Maps: start next animation in `onFinish()` of previous. But anyway, you can implement your own way for do that. For example, something like that, based on [Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) and [Chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) patterns:

```
public class CameraAnimationManager implements GoogleMap.CancelableCallback {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private List<CameraAnimation> mAnimations = new ArrayList<>();   // list of "animations"
    private int mCurrentAnimationIndex = -1;                         // index of current animation


    public CameraAnimationManager(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    }


    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // if next animation exists
        if (mCurrentAnimationIndex < mAnimations.size() - 1) {
            // animate it
            mCurrentAnimationIndex++;
            CameraAnimation currentAnimation = mAnimations.get(mCurrentAnimationIndex);
            animate(currentAnimation);
        } else {
            mCurrentAnimationIndex = -1;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        stopAnimation();
        mCurrentAnimationIndex = -1;
    }


    private void animate(CameraAnimation currentAnimation) {
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(currentAnimation.cameraUpdate, currentAnimation.duration, this);
    }


    public void clear() {
        stopAnimation();
        mAnimations.clear();
        mCurrentAnimationIndex = -1;
    }


    public void addAnimation(CameraAnimation animation) {
        mAnimations.add(animation);
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        // start sequence of animations from first
        if (mAnimations.size() > 0) {
            mCurrentAnimationIndex = 0;
            CameraAnimation currentAnimation = mAnimations.get(mCurrentAnimationIndex);
            animate(currentAnimation);
        }
    }


    public void stopAnimation() {
        mGoogleMap.stopAnimation();
    }


    // class for animation parameters store
    static class CameraAnimation {
        public CameraUpdate cameraUpdate;
        public int duration;


        public CameraAnimation(CameraUpdate cameraUpdate, int duration) {
            this.cameraUpdate = cameraUpdate;
            this.duration = duration;
        }
    }

}
```

`CameraAnimationManager` object implements `GoogleMap.CancelableCallback` and handles `onFinish()`. In that case new animation starts not directly from `onFinish()` of previous animation, but from `onFinish()` of `CameraAnimationManager` and you can control sequence of animation more flexible (each animation didn't store information about next animation and you can change animation order in `CameraAnimationManager.mAnimations`).

And you can call it this way:

```
...
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(13.807303, 100.518261), 16));
}
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mStartAnimationSequenceButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start_animation);
    mStartAnimationSequenceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mGoogleMap != null) {
                CameraUpdate location1 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(13.747871, 100.488370), 16);
                CameraUpdate location2 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(13.726253, 100.512301), 16);
                CameraUpdate location3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(13.692890, 100.490688), 16);

                mAnimationManager = new CameraAnimationManager(mGoogleMap);
                mAnimationManager.addAnimation(new CameraAnimationManager.CameraAnimation(location1, 3000) );
                mAnimationManager.addAnimation(new CameraAnimationManager.CameraAnimation(location2, 3000) );
                mAnimationManager.addAnimation(new CameraAnimationManager.CameraAnimation(location3, 3000) );
                mAnimationManager.startAnimation();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

for short trip along Chao Phraya River...